# Can we know each new gradle plugin format from the old way of classpath plugin definition?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I was having problem trying to find how can I add a Dagger Plugin in the latest Android Studio Generated Plugin, as I don't know how what's the new way of defining

- `classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.41'`.

I have to search much before finding it is now

- `id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.41' apply false`

I find no direct way to deduce the new way from the old one. Hence asking there, how can one know how to define a plugin is defined in the new gradle?

I check older Android Studio generated project, we have plugins defined below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

And the newer Android Studio generated project, plugins are now as below

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

Most of it looks like a 1-1 direct change, but `'kotlin-android'` becomes `'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'`. Is there a way for us to be sure of what it is?

Similarly for the classpath, it used to be

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.41'
}
```

and now

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.41' apply false
}
```

You'll see that

- `"com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1"` replace by 2 of them `'com.android.application' version '7.3.1'` and `'com.android.library' version '7.3.1'`
- `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin` becomes `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android`
- `com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin` becomes `com.google.dagger.hilt.android`

I cannot deduce the new way of name from the old way. Is there a way to determine the new naming?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to deduce it. From the [official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project) for writing plugins, you can register any `id` for your plugin:

```gradle
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("simplePlugin") {
            id = "org.example.greeting"
            implementationClass = "org.example.GreetingPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

and use it in another project:

```gradle
plugins {
    id("org.example.greeting") version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

For now, I always look up the usage from the plugin's guide or from https://plugins.gradle.org. Even the same plugin may have more than one `id`.